# Unity: Handling inheritance with JSONUtility.ToJSON

Tags: c#, json, inheritance, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use the new JSONUtility included with Unity 5.3.2 to serialize an object that contains an object that is the descendant of a base class. Here's an example:

```
[Serializable]
public class Class1
{
    public int class1Field = 1;
    public Class2 attributes = new Class3();
}
[Serializable]
public class Class3 : Class2
{
    public int class3Field = 3;
}
[Serializable]
public class Class2
{
    public int class2Field = 2;
}
```

If I then do:

```
Class1 myClass = new Class1();
Debug.Log(JsonUtility.ToJson(myClass));
```

The output is:

```
{"class1Field":1,"attributes":{"class2Field":2}}
```

As you can see, nothing from Class3 is being serialized. Interestingly if I do:

```
Debug.Log(JsonUtility.ToJson(myClass.attributes));
```

The output is :

```
{"class2Field":2,"class3Field":3}
```

which is what I expect. I know that I can do a pretty simple workaround using string.Format, but is there a more elegant solution to this issue? Am I perhaps not using the JSONUtility correctly? Or is this simply not supported by the JSONUtility at this time?

I'm investigating this functionality as I am using reflection to generate an object (which will come to replace the 'Class3' in this example), and then serialize the top-level object to which the reflected object belongs.

To be clear, my desired output is:

```
{"class1Field":1,"attributes":{"class2Field":2,"class3Field":3}}
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, and I've trawled forums for this. You can't deal with polymorphic types out of the box with the JSONUtility from Unity.

Recommended approaches include, using SharpSerializer, OdinInspector, JSON.Net.

Comment: Odin Serializer is fast, flexible and easy to use. I recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to read values directly from the JSON? The intended usage of JSON serialization is to be deserialized (to an object) once you need to read it again. You should call `JsonUtility.FromJson(string)` in order to re-read the data from the inherited classes.

Comment: I'm trying to serialize values to JSON (sorry for not being clear on that front). My issue is that the JSON object that I'm getting from the ToJSON method is not accounting for fields in objects derived from the base class.

Comment: Maybe try using a different serialization method? You could try using Newtonsoft.JSON, I've used that with inheritance, but I don't quite remember if it retained values.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for lately answer. You just missed type a keyword [SerializeField] on the "attributes" field. Unity can not serialize Reference Typed fields. (like Class,Custom Class, GameObject,MonoBehaviour...). For serialization it has to be a Value Typed (int,float ..). 
But still you want to serialize it then should add that [SerializeField] keyword attribues field and you also be careful using that keyword.

```
[Serializable] 
public class Class1
{
public int class1Field = 1;
[SerializeField]
public Class2 attributes = new Class3();
}
```

For detailed explanation:
[Unity SerializeField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html)